# How to create unique pair in dataframe using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe of few records as following:

```
1 0 1 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

I want to make a pair of two rows from the above dataframe randomly with no repetition.
The output should look like this:

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6   
0   1 0 1 0 1 1 1   4 
1   1 0 0 0 1 0 0   2
2   0 1 1 0 0 1 0   1
3   1 0 0 1 0 1 1   5
4   0 0 1 0 1 1 1   0
5   1 1 1 0 1 1 1   3
```

where last column contains the pair index.

Edit: If I use df['random_row_idx'] = np.random.permutation(df.index)
I get the output as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.random.permutation`.  `permutation` returns a randomly rearranged version of the array like thing being permuted.

To get what you asked for, run `permutaion` on the index

consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]])

df['random_row_idx'] = np.random.permutation(df.index)
df
```

[image]

---

However, you could have run `np.random.permutation` on the `df` itself.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]])


df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.permutation(df))

pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1, keys=['raw', 'permuted'])
```

[image]

Comment: The above code not working if I increase the size of dataframe.

Comment: I have put the output in the original question as an edit.